# Node server is not starting(command executes but not start the port)?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

when I enter "node server.js" then execution start and the cursor stuck at the starting of the next line what is the error.

```
const http = require('http');
http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log("hi from server");
    res.end('ok');
}).listen(8000);
```

[image]

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen.  Your server is waiting for connections.

Comment: IT does what you ask. It starts listening to a certain port and waits for input.

Comment: @Charlie can u please explain I can't understand I'm just start learning node.

Comment: Please, provide your code so we can explicitly know what are you trying to achieve

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Comment: Go to `localhost:8080` and check there once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal behaviour in fact if you add this line

```
console.log("Hi from Server");
```

Before

```
res.end("ok");
```

the cursor will print `"hi from server"`  and return to the same state..

Answer (score 0):

const test= http.createServer((re,res)=>{}                                    console.log(test,"hi from server)